# How to initialize a composite type in Julia-lang and be accessible to all functions without it being passed as a function parameter?

Tags: julia

In `Julia Lang`, how can a `composite type` have its parameter values allocated during runtime and be accessible to all the functions in the file?

I am looking for a feature similar to the 'static' keyword in Java. This is to avoid having to send the composite type in every function call as it is initialized from reading a file once and many functions rely on it; and not altered afterwards but the values are not known at compile time. ( I recall the usages of structs in Julia but am not sure if this would change anything )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Julia you can define global variables. Each Julia module (or baremodule) has its global scope.
   If you declare a global variable `const` then its type may not change (but its binding to a value possibly can).
2. The second part of your question is mutability of such a global constant. If the type of the global constant variable is immutable (e.g. numbers, strings, `struct`s, tuples, named tuples) then it will not be possible to change its value. However, it will be still possible to rebind the variable to a new value (as long as the new value has an appropriate type, we will get a warning that the binding has changed - see examples below).

A good example of such an approach in Julia Base is `Base.GLOBAL_RNG` variable (with the exception that it is mutable) - it holds a state of a default random number generator in Julia.

Here is a simple example using `struct`:

```
module E

struct A # immutable
    x::Int
end

const a = A(1) # global constant in module E

f() = println("a: $a")

function g()
     global a = A(10) # rebinding of a global variable requires global keyword
end

function h()
    a.x = 100
end

end # module
```

If you execute this in REPL you can test the behavior:

```
julia> E.a # we test the value of a global variable in module E
Main.E.A(1)

julia> E.f() # function f() from this module can access it
a: Main.E.A(1)

julia> E.h() # we cannot mutate fields of a
ERROR: type is immutable
Stacktrace:
 [1] setproperty! at .\sysimg.jl:9 [inlined]
 [2] h() at .\REPL[1]:16
 [3] top-level scope

julia> E.g() # but we can change the binding, we get a warning
WARNING: redefining constant a
Main.E.A(10)

julia> E.a
Main.E.A(10)    

julia> E.a = E.A(1000) # the binding cannot be changed outside the module
ERROR: cannot assign variables in other modules
Stacktrace:
 [1] setproperty!(::Module, ::Symbol, ::Main.E.A) at .\sysimg.jl:15
 [2] top-level scope
```

If you define a global constant in REPL then rebinding its value additionally emits a warning (here are some more examples with a global variable defined in REPL scope):

```
julia> global const z = E.A(5)
Main.E.A(5)

julia> z.x = 10
ERROR: type A is immutable
Stacktrace:
 [1] setproperty!(::Main.E.A, ::Symbol, ::Int64) at .\sysimg.jl:9
 [2] top-level scope

julia> z = E.A(2)
WARNING: redefining constant z
Main.E.A(2)

julia> z = "test" # we cannot change a type of const variable
ERROR: invalid redefinition of constant z
```

Here are the relevant sections of the Julia Manual:

- global scope: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Global-Scope-1
- constants: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Constants-1
- composite types: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Composite-Types-1
- `global` keyword: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/base/#global

EDIT: added missing `global` keyword in the definition of `g` function.

Comment: @Bogulmil Kaminski, if I now want to have a composite type, which can be accessed by every function with the same values, regardless of whether they were passed the reference to the composite type and get the same data, how would I do that?

Comment: Do you want to say that you have a composite type `A` which has a field `y` and that this field has the same value for each instance of `A` and field `x` which is instance specific? If yes you can use such a pattern `Base.getproperty(a::A, s::Symbol) = s == :x ? getfield(a, :x) ? (s == :y ? "get data from somewhere" : error("no such field"))`. Field `:y` isstatic and you hold its value somewhere outside `A`. You can similarly define `Base.setproperty!` to mutate `y`. But in general this pattern is not a typical design in Julia and I would simply use a second type to store static data.

Comment: Kaminski, thanks for the reply/answer. It does seem that Julia does not support this pattern as Java does.

Comment: @Vass I've just made an answer for a Fortran-related question, and I guess it may be useful for your purpose as well... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855209/is-there-a-common-block-in-julia (the type can also contain any collection types like Array, which can be allocated dynamically later in some function).

Comment: @roygvib Yes - this is a good example of what I meant. @Vass - agreed that you cannot mix static fields into a standard struct in Julia like in Java. As a side note - since you have asked about immutability - as opposed to Java if you work hard enough you can even mutate immutable objects, e.g. `y = ccall(:jl_ptr_to_array, Array{Int,1}, (Any, Ptr{Cvoid}, Any, Int32), Array{Int,1}, ccall(:jl_value_ptr, Ptr{Cvoid}, (Any,), a), (1,), false)`. Will create a mutable vector `y` which would allow you to change value of `a.x` as `y[1]` points to `a.x`. This is not something to recommend of course.