# Is there locally saved data (like Fortran's) in Julia?

Tags: fortran, julia

I am currently trying to re-write an entire Fortran 77 code into Julia.  Within this Fortran code, there are various local variables with the `SAVE` attribute (from a `SAVE` statement or when explicitly initialized in a `DATA` statement).

The problem is: I haven't been able to reproduce the same outcome that one would expect with these saved variables in Fortran.  For example, the code have many random generator programs extracted from the Numerical Recipies. In particular, `ran3.f`, called not only from within the main program, but from many different subroutines within it.

The `ran3.f` states:

```
FUNCTION ran3(idum)

c Returns a uniform random deviate between 0.0 and 1.0. 
c Set idum to any negative value to initialize or reinitialize the sequence.

INTEGER idum

INTEGER MBIG,MSEED,MZ

REAL ran3,FAC

PARAMETER (MBIG=1000000000,MSEED=161803398,MZ=0,FAC=1./MBIG)

INTEGER i,iff,ii,inext,inextp,k
INTEGER mj,mk,ma(55)    

SAVE iff,inext,inextp,ma

DATA iff /0/

if(idum.lt.0.or.iff.eq.0)then

CODE ... Etc, etc...

return
end
```

I have been able to reproduce the same results (random numbers) given a particular seed, and also to behave across the entire program and subroutines according to what is expected, but it was only by using a lot of returning variables and input variables.

How can the two lines

```
SAVE iff,inext,inextp,ma
DATA iff /0/
```

be replaced in Julia in order to acomplish the same behavior?

Comment: You ask about common blocks in particular, but there's no common block evident in the code fragment you provide.

Comment: Really, there is no common block in your code, please clarify.

Comment: In this case, I was referring to the SAVE and DATA blocks ...

Comment: But that is not a common block.

Comment: I've attempted to move the focus away from "common blocks" as you appear not to mean that.  If you think I've changed the question too much from what you mean, then please just roll the edit back.

Comment: @francescalus No problem!. Thanks. Btw, I will open another Questiion refering this issue, cause I haven't been able to understand some odd behavior of the SAVE and DATA statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate the code using SAVEed data or COMMON blocks as closely as possible, we can probably use a constant, global, mutable struct variable (placed in the top-level scope), e.g.

```
mutable struct myfunc_common_t     # or simply "type" in older versions
    num :: Int
    # constructors if necessary
end
const myfunc_common = myfunc_common_t( 0 )

function myfunc( idum )
    com = myfunc_common

    if idum < 0
        com.num = 100
    else
        com.num += 1
    end
    @show com.num
end

function myshow()
    @show myfunc_common.num
end

myfunc( -1 )
myfunc( 123 )
myfunc( 456 )
myfunc( 789 )

myshow()
```

which gives

```
com.num = 100
com.num = 101
com.num = 102
com.num = 103
myfunc_common.num = 103
```

The use of such constant globals are type-stable (as seen from @code_warntype) but it may be not suitable for parallel calculations (so be careful...). If possible, I think it would be nice to pass some type variable to a function explicitly (and mutate it within a function, or return a new type variable from the function). Indeed, "idum" is like a "state" variable, so we can replace it as a type variable :)

Comment: This can actually be very useful. It will take me a time to incorporate it to the ran3.jl & main.jl programs but I think it is the answer to my problem.  Thanks!